# What is business flow for accepting Credit card payment ?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have enabled the Credit Card Payment option on my Magento Site ?  I have also successfully to completed a Test Order using a MasterCard.

My qtn: What next ?  How do I process the Payment from the Card to our A/C ?  Do i need to setup a link from Admin or is manually done ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a merchant account or a PayPal account at minimum.

If you have a merchant account, the amount charged to the card will be transferred to your bank account by the payment processor.

Let me know if this is not what you meant. :)

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.   How do i go about setting up a Merchant A/C ?  Do I input details into "Payment Services" from Admin after i have spoken to the Bank ?

Comment: It depends on which merchant account you go with. Some of them will require an extra plugin/extension for Magento to communicate with their servers. Some popular merchant accounts include Authorize.net, CDGCOmmerce, etc. A modern payment processor like Stripe or Braintree is much easier to setup than a full blown merchant account but you'll need an extension to integrate them into Magento.

Comment: Thanks again.  I simply want VISA & Mastercard.   Do you any experience with these 2 ?

Comment: Yes any merchant accounts will allow you to process Visa and MasterCard.